# how to store the values of the checked rows in a NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have got a table view which is populated by json webservice url.I am using "UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark" for tick mark. when user multiple select the tableview I want all the selected row data to be stored in a single variable.Could you guys help me out. below is the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

if ([self.arForIPs containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
else {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}


NSString *imagefile1 = [media1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 


cell.textLabel.text=[story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.detailTextLabel.text=[descriptiondesc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines=2;
//cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
cell.imageView.image=img;

NSLog(@"BOOMMMM:%@",pileup);
return cell;
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've enabled multiselection you should be able to use UITableView's `indexPathsForSelectedRows` to get all the indices of the selected rows. With this you can refer back to your original data downloaded from the server and get the strings you need.

You can use it within `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to build a string of all the currently selected rows.

EDIT:
To store a few pieces of associated data together you can use an NSDictionary (or NSMutableDictionary if you need to edit it after creation). 
For example for your code, to store all the data for one row:

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
[dict setObject:[media1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"image"];
[dict setObject:[story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"story"];
[dict setObject:[descriptiondesc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"desc"];
```

or you could create it straight into a regular NSDictionary, see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: cud u gimme an example of how to store the the data of thecheck row in a single variable i tried but i was unsucessful

Comment: Added some code for you to store stuff in one object per row.

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin : I also have implemented in the same manner.. :)

Comment: By the way, if you're working with json you can check out these frameworks: http://cocoaobjects.com/?s=json Some of them may be able to parse straight into NSDictionary's for you.

Comment: i ve used the above 3 lines i m getting NSMutableArray doesnt respond to setObject.the app is getting crashed.NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
  [dict setObject:[self.story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  NSLog(@"room:%@",dict);

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableDictionary Make sure you use setObject: forKey: and you're using an NSMutableDictionary, not NSMutableArray.

Comment: i m not using forKey..is there any alternative of the storing in NSMutableDictionary

Comment: You can't not use forKey, that's the method you would need. Then you can pull the data out of the dictionary with [dict objectForKey:@"image"]; (or one of the other keys).